# AEM: content masking and internal redirect conflicts

Tags: redirect, adobe, aem, sling

I have a conflict between dispatcher httpd conf and sling internalredirects.
I have <"domain">/content/abc/1.html and <"domain">/content/def/1.html which should be respectively be resolved to /1.html.

I have tried performing below config changes in virtual host of httpd.conf:

```
 RewriteRule ^/content/abc/(.*)$ /$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

RewriteRule ^/content/def/(.*)$ /$1 [NE,L,R=301]

Also I have tried with sling:internal redirect with content/abc/$1, content/def/$1, $1

But the site always renders the abc content as that is what it gets in the first interal redirect. Could you kindly let me know if problem? and solution for the same?
**************In simple terms***************
Both the below URLS: 
https://mysite.city.com/content/abc/en/quote.html
https://mysite.city.com/content/def/en/quote.html
should be rendered as:
https://mysite.city.com/en/quote.html

Comment: Have you defined the proper virtualhost for each AEM site?

Comment: It is preferable to use Sling mappings instead of Apache rules to manage a multisite implementation.

Comment: @ronnyfm: Both the AEM site is one. Its the same domain. Updated the question with below: Both the below URLS: 

https://mysite.city.com/content/abc/en/quote.html and 
https://mysite.city.com/content/def/en/quote.html

should be rendered as:
https://mysite.city.com/en/quote.html

Comment: Hmm, I still have my doubts, a single site should look like mysite.city.com/content/mysite, and then you hide the content/mysite using Sling mappings. But here, there is no way to say which quote should be rendered and AEM simply use the first entry that matches.

Comment: @ronnyfm: Yup exactly that is what I am facing. https://mysite.city.com/content/abc/en/quote.html https://mysite.city.com/content/def/en/quote.html should be rendered as: https://mysite.city.com/en/quote.html . Here what is happening is in the sling: interalredirect I have given both: /content/def and /content/abc in the same order. Its always rendering /content/def's en.html page even if I try the https://mysite.city.com/content/abc/en/quote.html